# how to mirror gitlab CE repo on gitlab.com and automatically update?

Tags: git, gitlab

TLDR; I need to backup a repo and keep it automatically up to date for free.

I've got some repos hosted on gitlab.com, free edition. I want to mirror them to any other free online repo store and keep this backup automatically updated when the origin repo on gitlab.com receives and update (push).

Are there any free repo services that will do an automatic pull of updates, e.g. daily from another origin repo?

Alternatively, how would I set up a cron on a 3rd party server to tell the backup repo to update itself with any new pushes from the origin repo, e.g. daily? (or some similar arrangement).

I don't want to use gitlab webhooks for various regions (and actually don't need to, a scheduled daily backup is fine).

I do have a paid github account I could use if that were the only option.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a python package that allows doing that manually:

[github2gitlab 1.5.5](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/github2gitlab)

I also found by googling a project that provides "Continuous repository synchroniser between GitHub and GitLab" but I haven't yet tried it.

[github-gitlab-sync](https://gitlab.doc.ic.ac.uk/tw1509/github-gitlab-sync)

There is a discussion on Gitlab Issues that requests to move the mirroring ability to Gitlab CE:

[Can repository mirroring be incorporated into Gitlab CE?](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/18732)

Hope this helps :)